# I have data in array and have to show in Laravel blade template but its showing error when try to get name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have to get all orgnizations name without using loop because I cant two loops.  What i am trying to in Blade:

```
<?php $number = 0; $org_names_counter = 0;?>
@foreach($managers as $items)
    {{--  @foreach($org_names as $key => $org_name) --}}

    <?php $number++; ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$number}}</td>
        <td>{{$items->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$items->email}}</td>
        <td> <?php echo $org_names[$org_names_counter]['name']; ?> </td>
        <td>
            <a href='editmanagers/{{ $items->id }}' class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
            </a>
            <a href='deletemanagers/{{ $items->id }}' class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip">
                <i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function managersdata()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role == "admin") {
        $org_names = [];
        $data = Managers::where('role', 'managers')->get();
        foreach ($data as $datas) {
            $org_names[] = Organization::where('id', $datas->organization_id)->get();
        }
        $managers = Managers::where('role', 'managers')->get();

        return view('users.managersdetails', compact('managers', 'org_names'));
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Undefined index: name (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/EASI/resources/views/users/managersdetails.blade.php)

And this is the output I am getting:

```
Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Organization Object ( [table:protected] => organization [primaryKey] => id [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => city ) [connection:protected] => mysql [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) ) [1] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Organization Object ( [table:protected] => organization [primaryKey] => id [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => city ) [connection:protected] => mysql [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => test1 [email] => test1@gmail.com [city] => test ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => test1 [email] => test1@gmail.com [city] => test ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) ) [2] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Organization Object ( [table:protected] => organization [primaryKey] => id [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => city ) [connection:protected] => mysql [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => test 2 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => hhhhhhhhhhh ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => test 2 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => hhhhhhhhhhh ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) ) [3] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Organization Object ( [table:protected] => organization [primaryKey] => id [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => city ) [connection:protected] => mysql [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) ) [4] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Organization Object ( [table:protected] => organization [primaryKey] => id [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => email [2] => city ) [connection:protected] => mysql [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => test 4 [email] => test@gmail.com [city] => jhgkjhk ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: You'll better off using proper relationships.

Comment: Show your Model and controller as well.

Comment: What is the error?  What is your question?

Comment: @Don'tPanic error is 
Undefined index: name (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/EASI/resources/views/users/managersdetails.blade.php)

Comment: @HassaanAli controller is 
   public function managersdata(){
      
      if(Auth::user()->role ==  "admin" ){
      $org_names = [];
      $data = Managers::where('role', 'managers')->get(); 
      
      foreach($data as $datas){
        $org_names[] = Organization::where('id', $datas->organization_id)->get();  
      }  
   
 
      
        $managers = Managers::where('role', 'managers')->get(); 
        
        return view('users.managersdetails', compact('managers','org_names'));
       
        }

Comment: Edit your question, add errors and code there, formatted, so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing:

> Undefined index name

Tells us this is the problem line:

```
echo $org_names[$org_names_counter]['name'];
```

Looking at the controller code, that variable is set up with:

```
$org_names[] = Organization::where('id', $datas->organization_id)->get();
```

The Eloquent method [`get()` will return a *collection*](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#collections), so `$org_names` is an array of collections.  `$org_names[0]` is a *collection* of `Organization`s, not a single `Organization`.

You can also see this in the dump you've shown:

```
Array (
    [0] => Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection Object (
```

`$org_names[0]` is a collection.

To access those, you would have to do something like:

```
foreach ($org_names[$org_names_counter] as $org) {
    echo $org->name;
    // ...
}
```

But looking at the code, it seems clear that there should only be 1 element in the collection, as you are selecting by ID.  In that case, you are after the single result.  To get a single matching result, use:

```
$org_names[] = Organization::where('id', $datas->organization_id)->first();
```

Now `$org_names[]` is just an array of `Organization`s, and your existing view code will work.